# Visio: prompt for page data when creating new page?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is there a way to have Visio prompt for page data when a new page is added similar to how there's a option to bring up the shape data dialog when adding a new shape to a page?

Comment: The option to bring up the shape data dialog is an attribute of the shape, not the page. So, it doesn't work for adding any old shape to a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available in any Visio version. Even if you create shape data for a page and set the Ask flag to true and duplicate the page the shape data gets copied but Visio does not prompt for the data to be entered.

If you do the same with a shape then upon duplication of the shape Visio will ask for the data to be entered. So either this is a bug in Visio or it is purposely disabled.

However, when a page is duplicated that contains a shape containing shape data with the Ask flag set then Visio still does not prompt for data. If there were many, many shapes with this flag set then it could take forever to enter the data. I can see why this is disabled.